# is not assignable to type 'LocationDescriptor<unknown> | ((location: Location<unknown>) => LocationDescriptor<unknown>)'

Tags: typescript, react-router-dom

this my code

```
14      <NavLink
15        to={{
16          pathname: `/confirmMail`,
17          user: { email, nickName },
18        }}
19      >
20       {"Confirm Email"}
21     </NavLink>
```

on line 17 I get the error

> Type '{ pathname: string; user: { email: string; nickName: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'LocationDescriptor | ((location: Location) => LocationDescriptor)'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'user' does not exist in type 'LocationDescriptorObject | ((location: Location) => LocationDescriptor)'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`user` is not a valid property in the `to` object. If you want to pass information to the next route, you should use the `state` property, or pass it via query params. Here is an example of using the `state` property:

```
<NavLink
  to={{
    pathname: `/confirmMail`,
    state: { user: { email, nickName } },
  }}
>
  {"Confirm Email"}
</NavLink>
```

Here is the [documentation for NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink) (which extends from Link, the component where the `to` prop is implemented).